# Creating new po files with a po editor

Tags: translation, gettext, po

I tried some [po editor softwares](http://alternativeto.net/software/better-po-editor/). I wonder why none of do not allow creating a new po file from scratch or adding new entry to an existed one. Is there any hack so they let creating new entries? (I know that po files are plain text and can be edited in any text editor!)

Comment: You don't explain why you want to create a new PO file instead of having your software build system create them.

Comment: @Dwayne I want use PO files to make a PHP site multilingual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PO editors are for translating a PO file from one language to another.  They aren't designed to create PO files.  Your PO files should be created as part of a build system not by an editor.

If you want to create them for testing then they are pretty easy to create either by using another existing PO files or by uncompiling an MO file (using msgunfmt).

Comment: I want use PO files to make a MVC PHP site multilingual. It there any tools that can make a PO file from the PHP files?

Comment: Check out [php2po](http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/toolkit/php2po) - which will convert strings arrays and similar constructs that PHP dev often use for localisation.  If you are using Gettext then use xgettext to extract localisation strings.

Answer (score 1):

## Script auto create .po file, auto add all text from you code

1. Add load_theme_textdomain('my-textdomain',**DIR**.'/languages/');
2. Create folder wp-content/themes/MY_THEME/languages (add your language .mo file to this folder)
3. Create **po.php** and add this script:

```html
<?php /*Script by Sien.com.vn */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

require(''.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php' );


function title_p($title) {

$title='Po create';   

return $title;}
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'title_p' );


$robots_p='noindex,nofollow';   

get_header();  


echo '<div id="content" class="col col-100">';


if(current_user_can('manage_options')){

function write_txt($path,$content,$type){
$file=fopen($path,$type) or die();
fwrite($file,$content);
fclose($file);
return TRUE;
}



if(isset($_POST['lang'])){
$lang_code=pathinfo($_POST['lang'],PATHINFO_FILENAME);

load_textdomain('this_lang',__DIR__.'/'.$lang_code.'.mo');


$textdomain=$_POST['textdomain'];


$txt='';

function sfile($dir, $ext) {
 global $textdomain;



$globFiles = glob("$dir".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."*.$ext");
$globDirs = glob("$dir/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);

foreach ($globDirs as $dir) {
sfile($dir, $ext);

}

foreach ($globFiles as $file=>$path) {



$txt.=file_get_contents($path,FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);



}


preg_match_all('/(translate|__|_e|esc_attr__|esc_attr_e|esc_html__|esc_html_e) ?\( ?(\'|\")(.+?)(\'|\") ?, ?(\'|\")'.$textdomain.'(\'|\") ?\)/',$txt,$output);



foreach(array_unique($output[3]) as $v){

 if(isset($v)){
 
write_txt(''.__DIR__.'/po.dat',''.(str_replace(array("\'",'\"'),array("'",'"'),$v)).'**$!3|\\/**','a+');
 }
}


}
sfile(get_template_directory(),'php');



$get=file_get_contents(''.__DIR__.'/po.dat');

$k=explode('**$!3|\\/**',$get);


foreach(array_unique($k) as $v){
 
 if(!empty($v)){ 
 
if($v==__($v,'this_lang')){
write_txt(''.__DIR__.'/po.dat.empty','
msgid "'.$v.'"
msgstr ""
','a+');
}else{
write_txt(''.__DIR__.'/po.dat.isset','
msgid "'.$v.'"
msgstr "'.__($v,'this_lang').'"
','a+');
}
 
 
 }

 }
 
if(empty(file_get_contents(''.__DIR__.'/po.dat.isset')) && empty(file_get_contents(''.__DIR__.'/po.dat.empty'))){
  echo '<div class="error">Error, Textdomain <b>'.$textdomain.'</b> not found!</div>';
 }else{

write_txt(''.__DIR__.'/'.$lang_code.'.po','# '.$lang_code.' LANG
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"PO-Revision-Date: 2017-11-23 22:26+0700\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=1; plural=0;\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 2.0.4\n"
"Language: vi_VN\n"
"Project-Id-Version: Sien\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: \n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"




'.file_get_contents(''.__DIR__.'/po.dat.isset').'
'.file_get_contents(''.__DIR__.'/po.dat.empty').'
','w+');
 

echo '<div class="success"><span style="color:blue">Success</span> -> Saved to: '.__DIR__.'/ <b>'.$lang_code.'.po</b></div>';

unlink(''.__DIR__.'/po.dat');
unlink(''.__DIR__.'/po.dat.isset');
unlink(''.__DIR__.'/po.dat.empty');



}

 

}





echo '<form action="" method="POST">
<div class="menu bd text-center"><p>Language: <select name="lang">';

foreach(glob("".__DIR__."/*.mo") as $path) {echo '<option value="'.$path.'">'.pathinfo($path,PATHINFO_FILENAME).'</option>';}

echo '</select></p>';




$txt='';
function stext($dir, $ext) {
$globFiles = glob("$dir".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."*.$ext");
$globDirs = glob("$dir/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
foreach ($globDirs as $dir) {stext($dir, $ext);}

foreach ($globFiles as $file=>$path) {
 if($path!=__FILE__){
$txt.=(str_replace(' ','',file_get_contents($path,FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH)));
 }

}


preg_match_all('/load_theme_textdomain\((\'|\")(.+?)(\'|\")/',$txt,$gtextdomain);
$td='';
foreach($gtextdomain[2] as $text){
 
 if(!empty($text)){
 $td.='<option value="'.$text.'">'.$text.'</option>';
 }


}



write_txt(__DIR__.'/textdomain.dat',$td,'a+');
}
stext(get_template_directory(),'php');


$textdomain=file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/textdomain.dat');
if(empty($textdomain)){echo '<div class="error">Not found textdomain [ <b>load_theme_textdomain ("you-textdomain","path_to_language_folder");</b> ]</div>';}else{
echo '<p>Textdomain: <select name="textdomain">'.$textdomain.'</select></p>';
}

echo '<p>
<input type="submit" value="Create new.po file"/>
</p>
</div>
</form>';





unlink(__DIR__.'/textdomain.dat');




}



echo '</div>';


get_footer();
```

4. Go to **youdomain/wp-content/themes/MY_THEME/languages/po.php** and create .po file
5. Copy **wp-content/themes/MY_THEME/languages/[LANG].po** to desktop and open with **Poedit** -> Compile MO -> copy [LANG].mo to **languages** folder

Comment: Thanks, I hope to be able to use your code in future.